# Rally Query using not keyword

Tags: rally

How can you use NOT in a query?  I am trying this:  not ( Name contains "spike" )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Rally's WSAPI does not currently support a not contains operator.  Please vote up this idea here:

http://ideas.rallydev.com/ct/ct_a_view_idea.bix?c=FB85CCBC-A755-42AD-AF8E-6F2B539BECEC&idea_id=61DF4D37-AFB9-487C-9046-8461D5080231

Answer (score 2):

It appears they now allow :

!contains, i.e.

```
( Name !contains "spike" )
```

which should work for this.

I also notice that both the contains and !contains are case-insensitive, meaning they will return the same results whether you use "spike" or "SPIKE" (at least, I believe this is the case).